# Check if current process is running using Python?

Tags: python, process

I need to add a function to my python script that checks if the current script is already running. If it is then it will quit, if not it continues running the script. I've looked into methods of doing this but I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to just execute system commands... if on linux ps aux | grep python <name of script> ? see this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056/how-do-you-check-in-linux-with-python-if-a-process-is-still-running

Comment: Well I need it to work on Windows too, not just Linux

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the psutil module: http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Comment: [Check if a process is running using Python on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7647167/608639), [How to check if a process is still running using Python on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38056/608639), [Python check if a process is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787120/608639), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you mean "cross-platform single instance of application written in python". Try this workable solution: [Python: single instance of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program/1265445#1265445)

Answer (score 1):

You need to communicate using a shared resource.  In the simplest sense, you use the resource as a mutex.  Lock or pid files are commonly used this way on *nix by using the filesystem as that shared resource.

Depending on need, you can use a shared resource that allows communication; e.g. a web browser executed to open a given URL will communicate the URL to an existing process, if there is one.

The type of shared resources available is platform-specific.