# Python - Easiest way to check if a process is running

Tags: python-3.x, process, detection

When using a windows machine, what would be the easiest way to check if a process in running, using python. (Using Python, what's the best way to get a True/False answer for whether a process like "Notepad.exe" is running.)

Assuming that I cannot use WMI for reasons unknown, I would guess that the best/most upvoted answer would be something with psutil.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I have tried previous answers to similar questions when they are resolved with psutil, but I keep getting syntax errors. I guess I just don't know how to use psutil.

Comment: Post the code and the errors you are getting. Try examples from [psutil.Processes](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#processes)

Comment: @sk11 Thank you for the link, solved myself. If will help people with a similar problem, I can post as edit. (or answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a process is running or not on Windows with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not-on-windows-with-python)