# Python Kill a program but check first

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code to kill my application through task manager and it works successfully. However, now I want to first check if the program exists before it kills it, any suggestions?

```
def close_SAP()"
   call('taskkill /im saplogon.exe /t /f')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   close_SAP()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python check if a process is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here It will check whether the program exists or not and if yes it kill it:

```
import os
r = os.popen('tasklist /v').read().strip().split('\n')
name  = "saplogon.exe"
for i in range(len(r)):
    if name in r[i]:
        os.system("taskkill /im %s" %(name))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, simple and clean!

Comment: Its glad to help you dude :)

Answer (score 0):

im assuming youre working on windows since the sap.exe.
so this could be helpful for you.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

i cant test it myself since im on a linux machine atm but i got it from here http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html