# Kill process and all its child processes after a Popen

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow-serving

So I have a situation where I have an Flask endpoint A, endpoint B and two other scripts `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

When I call endpoint A, I will do a call for `foo.py` with Popen and store its PID.
On `foo.py`, it makes a call to `bar.py` using Popen, which makes **another** call, again, using Popen. The process opened on `bar.py` is a server (to be more specific, it's a tf-serving server), which will be hanging forever when I do an p.wait(). Later on, I would like to use endpoint B to end the whole process triggered by A.

The situation can be something like:

Flask's endpoints:

```
import os
import json
import signal
from subprocess import Popen

from flask import current_app
from flask import request, jsonify

@app.route('/A', methods=['GET'])
def a():
    p = Popen(['python', '-u','./foo.py'])
    current_app.config['FOO_PID'] = p.pid
    return jsonify({'message': 'Started successfully'}), 200

@inspection.route('/B', methods=['GET'])
def b():
    os.kill(current_app.config['FOO_PID'], signal.SIGTERM)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Stopped successfully'}), 200
```

foo.py:

```
p = Popen(['python' ,'-u', './bar.py', '--serve'])
while True:
   continue
```

bar.py:

```
command = f'tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=obj_det --model_base_path=./model'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=sys.stderr, stdout=sys.stdout)
p.wait()
```

Unfortunately when I kill `foo.py` using endpoint B, the process created by `bar.py` (ie. the server) will not end. **How can I kill the server?**

Please consider a solution that is OS agnostic.

Comment: ok, on B endpoint, use the PID of A to track its availability. I also tell you to uniquely name your process so when you track A from B also check to see if A has the good name.  if A is ended then also ends B

Comment: @user1438644 how could I track it?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a package like `psutil` allows you to recursively iterate and access of all child processes related to a certain PID. This will effectively allow you to kill all nested processes. Documentation for `psutil` https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil.

```py
import json
import signal
from subprocess import Popen

from flask import current_app
from flask import request, jsonify
from psutil import Process

@app.route('/A', methods=['GET'])
def a():
    p = Popen(['python', '-u','./foo.py'])
    current_app.config['FOO_PID'] = p.pid
    return jsonify({'message': 'Started successfully'}), 200

@inspection.route('/B', methods=['GET'])
def b():
   pid = current_app.config['FOO_PID']
   parent = Process(pid)
   for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
      child.kill()
   parent.kill()
   return jsonify({'message': 'Stopped successfully'}), 200
```