# How do I figure out if my browser is already running in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, browser, psutil

So far, I have tried PSUTIL to see if firefox is running and it works, BUT the problem is firefox's PID keeps changing every time I close and reopen it. Is there anyway I can always check whether firefox is already running or not?

PS: Not using selenium right now, just my regular firefox browser

Comment: `psutil` is the right tool to do that. You can find more information in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not/7788702). 

And why is it a problem that the PID is changing every time?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your python script :

```
l = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'firefox' in p.info['name']]
if(len(l)>0):
    print("Firefox is running")
else:
    print("Firefox is not running")
```

Comment: "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"


Edit: I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
    if p.info['name'] == "firefox.exe":
        print("yes", (p.info['name']))
```