# Getting 'psutil.AccessDenied (pid=6836)' error using psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I want to check if a program is running or not, so I searched and I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788702/13518924) , in this way:

```
import psutil
if "notepad.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
    print('program is running')
else:
    print('not running')
```

but I get this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    if "notepad.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
  File "~/temp.py", line 2, in <genexpr>
    if "notepad.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
  File "~\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 630, in name
    name = self._proc.name()
  File "~\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 750, in name
    return os.path.basename(self.exe())
  File "~\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 681, in wrapper
    raise convert_oserror(err, pid=self.pid, name=self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=6836)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

am I doing something wrong with this simple code?
or is there another alternative way?

EDIT: sorry, i forgot to mention im on windows, not linux,  can u give me solutions for windows platform?

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not

Comment: You may need to interpret the program with elevated privileges.

Comment: In bash just add sudo `sudo python name.py`. In windows become an administrator and then run.

Comment: what about windows 10? make it force run as admin? if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You may need administrator / root privileges on your system.

If you can get a command prompt, try to use `sudo` before running python to elevate your privileges to the root user. Or give your user Administrator level access.