# Python: test if windows application is loaded

Tags: python, windows

I am playing around with some windows desktop automation scripts using packages `mouse` and `keyboard`.

My question is, however, not related to these packages but more of a general thing I cannot solve.

Let's say I use python to control my mouse and open an application via automatic mouse click.

**Question:**
Is there a way to programmatically determine
(i) what application the mouse clicked on
(ii) if the application is fully loaded

Any hint would help as long as it involves using python (if possible).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not

Comment: Thx. That helped a lot.