# How can I use psutil to constantly check if a process/application is running?

Tags: python, tkinter, psutil

I tried using the answer in [Python check if a process is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not) to help me. However, when I tried to implement psutil into my code it did not work successfully.

I created a GUI using tkinter and I am trying to make it so as soon as the application opens, the application will be moved to the selected location. Am I using psutil incorrectly?

Here's a portion of my code:

```
if clicked1.get() == "Google Chrome"
    os.startfile(r"{google chrome file location}")
    time.sleep(4)                    # time.sleep to allow the application time to open
    app.connect(path=r"{google chrome file location}")
    app1 = app.top_window()
    app1.move_window(-20, -2150)     # moves application to those x and y coordinates
    time.sleep(.5)                   # gives the application time to move before maximizing
    app1.maximize()
```

Here's my code when I tried to implement psutil:

```
 if clicked1.get() == "Google Chrome"
    os.startfile(r"{google chrome file location}")
    while True:
        if "Google Chrome" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()
            app.connect(path=r"{google chrome file location}")
            app1 = app.top_window()
            app1.move_window(-20, -2150)     # moves application to those x and y coordinates
            time.sleep(.5)                   # gives the application time to move before maximizing
            app1.maximize()
            break                 # breaks from the loop when the application is started and is moved
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: @BryanOakley It doesn't work because when I run the program, it will start the application but the application never gets moved to the selected screen and maximized

Comment: You have a potentially infinite loop. Have you debugged the loop to see what the `if` statement is doing on each iteration?