# Why am I getting access denied when program is not running?

Tags: python, psutil

I have a simple piece of code taken mostly from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not-on-windows-with-python/7788702#7788702), with some adjustments:

```
import psutil

try:
    if "firefox.exe" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
        print('Firefox is running')
    else:
        print('Firefox is not running')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

If Firefox is running when I run this code, it prints the expected `Firefox is running`. But if Firefox isn't running, I get `psutil.AccessDenied (pid=9092)` instead of the expected `Firefox is not running`.

I also noticed that if `firefox.exe` is mis-spelled, I get the `AccessDenied` error again. I could just `print('Firefox is not running')` inside the `except` block, but that doesn't seem very smart.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you don't have permission to get the name of PID 9092.

Comment: How would I fix that? run as admin?

Comment: Since you have tested that it works when the firefox running,just handle permission error exception and print not running.

Comment: Right.  You don't CARE what the privileged processes are.  You just care that you didn't see Firefox.

Comment: one problem, the `PermissionError` does not catch the `psutil.AccessDenied (pid=9092)` error

Comment: except (PermissionError, AccessDenied):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process_iter()` allows you to specify the attributes that should be returned. So tell it to just return the names, and compare them.

```
if any(p.info['name'] == "firefox.exe" for p in psutil.process_iter(['name'])):
```

Got this from the documentation:

[Find process by name](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-process-by-name)

Comment: Fixed it. Need to use `p.info`

Answer (score 0):

Because this  `(p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())` is a generator, and when the process is not spotted in a user processes, it tries to list the system ones. Consider suppressing this exception with warning like `print('Firefox is not running by current user')`

> I get psutil.AccessDenied (pid=9092)

Other possible reason is that process was terminated after the iterator got pid to retrieve. Since you can't be sure the process won't disappear while your python process was suspended by OS scheduler, ignorance seems to be a legit solution.

UPD: aaand that's the case (dead process yielded)
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/c3e63b4dd59f1724a7fa29371e53dfa7f46cbcd3/psutil/__init__.py#L1453-L1465

When you tried to access the process name (which wasn't cached), it was already dead. So I would just skip it instead of behaving like it's  running.