# Check which Python process is running 'myscript.py' on Windows, Linux

Tags: python, psutil

Finding out that Python is running is rather easy. But how can I find out which Python process is the one running `myscript.py`?

I took help from this [Check if a process is running or not on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not-on-windows) eventually using `psutil` as simple as:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    if "python"  in str(proc.info).lower(): 
       print(proc.info)
```

This results e.g. in this output:

```
{'pid': 34461, 'name': 'python'}
{'pid': 1245157, 'name': 'python'}
{'pid': 1433410, 'name': 'python'}
{'pid': 2176252, 'name': 'python3.11'}
{'pid': 2894859, 'name': 'python'}
{'pid': 2973672, 'name': 'python'}
{'pid': 3354315, 'name': 'python'}
```

Very easy so far, but which of these Python processes is the one which runs `myscript.py`?

A solution must be possible from within Python and must run on Windows, and Linux. Hopefully, also be on Mac.

Comment: add `cmdline` to the list and then parse the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution working on MacOs, Linux and Windows:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    if "python"  in str(proc.info).lower(): 
       print(proc.cmdline())
```

It gives a useful output that you can use to find the good process :

```
['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', '/Users/XXX/Code/test.py']
```

Comment: Duuuh, so obvious, how could I have possibly missed it? Many thanks.
Can now add that it not only works on Mac, as you said, but also on Win10, and Linux!

Comment: Ahah it happens, i add it to the answer :)