Main script that start, stop and monitor others (Python Watchdog)
Original ask question:
I have a watchdog.py this script should handle the other scripts let's say test1.py and test2.py
script1.py and script2.py run on their own in loop as let's say closed modules.
The only Task of main.py is to start, stop the other if needed and restart them if the run into an error (monitor).
Have looked at popen and multi threading but I found no way to monitor and restart.
Can someone lead me a way to the right procedure or give me an example how do to that?
My solution so far that works (On Linux):
In the main i call every script with a popen subprocess and kill it with pkill. From my point of view its not the best solution what brings me back to my main question for the right procedure...
watchdog.py:
Main Script that runs in a infinite loop and start/stop/restart scripts if necessary
whatchdog.ini:
The config file where the scripts and start/stop/ restart flags are defined. It can by altered manually or by another script while whatchdog.py runs.
test1.py:
A simple test script that prints "Hello Test 1" every 10sec
test2.py:
A simple test script that prints "Hello Test 1" every 10sec but run in an error after 2x (will trigger an restart if flag in the ini is 1)
Put everything in an Folder and run watchdog.py its a test script the only thing is missing is the possibility to set a full file path for the scripts but that is easy to change if you want to use it ...
Code watchdog.py:
    import time
    import os
    import subprocess
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import configparser

    #Time interval how often should the watchdog script run (sec.)
    interval = 10

    # // FUNCTIONS //

    # Function to read the config file

    def read_config(section, key):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('watchdog.ini')
        return config[section][key]


    # Function to start the Script as subprocess inside multiprocessing process

    def start_script(scriptname):
        sub_dict = {}
        sub_id = "sub_id_" + scriptname
        sub_variable_name = "start_" + scriptname
        sub_variable_value = ['python', '' + str(scriptname) + '.py']
        sub_dict[sub_variable_name] = sub_variable_value
        sub_dict[sub_id] = sub_id
        globals()[sub_dict[sub_id]] = subprocess.Popen(sub_dict[sub_variable_name])

    # Function to kill (stop) a subprocess/script

    def stop_script(scriptname):
        command = 'pkill -f ' + str(scriptname) + '.py'
        os.system(command);

    # Check if subprocess/script is running
    def running_script(scriptname):
        sub_id = 'sub_id_' + scriptname
        if sub_id in locals() or sub_id in globals():
            if eval(sub_id).poll() == None:
                #print(scriptname + ' is running')
                return('running')
            else:
                #print(scriptname + ' not running')
                return('stoped')
        else:
            return('not defined')

    # // END FUNCTIONS //

    # // MAIN LOOP //

    while True:
        # Loop throug sections of the config file to get all scripts
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('watchdog.ini')
        all_section_names: list[str] = config.sections()
        for section_name in all_section_names:
            #print(section_name)
            #Get start/stop/restart flags for the specific script
            start = int(read_config(section_name, 'start'))
            stop = int(read_config(section_name, 'stop'))
            restart = int(read_config(section_name, 'restart'))
            #Check Status running / stoped / not defined
            status = str(running_script(section_name))
            #Start script if start=1 and wasnt started before
            if start == 1 and status == 'not defined':
                start_script(section_name)
                print(section_name + ' started')
            # Stop the script if stop = 1
            if stop == 1 and status != 'stoped' and status != 'not defined':
                stop_script(section_name)
                print(section_name + ' stoped')
            # Restart script if restart = 1 and script was started before
            if restart == 1 and status == 'stoped':
                stop_script(section_name)
                start_script(section_name)
                print(section_name + ' restarted')
        time.sleep(interval)


    # // END MAIN LOOP //

Code watchdog.ini:
[test1]
start = 1
stop = 0
restart = 0

[test2]
start = 1
stop = 0
restart = 1

Code test1.py
# Scripts prints 'Hello Test 1' every 10sec and run without problems
import time

while True:
    print('Hello Test 1')
    time.sleep(10)

Code test2.py:
# Scripts prints 'Hello Test2" every 10sec but after two times it runs into an error and need to be / could be restarted by the main.py
import time

while True:
    print("Hello Test 2")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Hello Test 2")
    time.sleep(10)
    get.value


Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example that demonstrates your problem

Please don't repost.

Hi SIGHUP
I have provided a description how the script should act with the question how to start.
I i would know it should or can be done with lets say popen i can work it out.
But as noted in the text i have no clue where to start ...

That's not how Stackoverflow works

Monitoring will completely depend on how your scripts signal an error. Will they just crash and stop running? Will they pass some kind of error message? Depending how you design your scripts the monitor will work one way or the other. Why don't you just monitor if the scripts are running and if not launch them again?

Ok so Stackoverflow is not for beginners to ask for help ?
Onlything i want to know where i should start i dont await a full code ..
I have looked at popen and multithreading but i see now way to implement a monitoring for the threats there ,,

You mean that this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not-on-windows  is not helpful? Just check if a process is running, if it has stopped running launch it again.

Hi Cincinnatus
Thats exactly my point i want just start stop and monitor if the script is running if not restart it. Start Stop is not the real problem but how i monitor if its running and restart

run you scripts in docker containers set to restart. logging can be moniftored via docker

If it's possible I don't want implement third party modules or software but thanks for the Tips !

I thinked about multi threading to call the scripts then get the pid in the scripts and write it to a config file the main then gets the pids from the file and check if the threads are running and if not restart them. But i think it's a very complicated solution there should be a better way. I am currently on my way home tomorrow I will work an a code example

I have worked a litte bit more on the watchdog script.
The scripts gets startet over subprocess.
The subprocesses managed in a dictionary to start/stop/restart
The whole function run in a thread so it dont block the main process and multiple watchdogs can be started.
Outcome is a phyton watchdog script with the following futures:

Keep an eye on your scripts start/stop/restart them automatically if necessary
Dont block your main script
You can start more then one watchdog parallel
Easy implementation and configuration
Clean exit over the main process so nor more wild running uboat scripts

I have uploaded everything to github with example files and description.
You can find it here:
Python-Watchdog on github
Thanks to everybody !
