# Check with Python if Outlook is already open, if not open it

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-2013

I wrote a python script which often sends mails via Outlook. The problem is if I don't have Outlook open, no mails will be send. (I use Outlook 2013)
Now I want to check at the beginning of my script if Outlook is already open, and if not I want to open it with python to avoid the errors.

How do I check if Outlook is already running via Python 2.7 ? To start Outlook I would use the simple code:

```
import os
os.startfile("outlook")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may use a try and except block.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send emails *without* using outlook? For example, you should look into using the built-in [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) module to send email using the **S**imple **M**ail **T**ransfer **P**rotocol; it will simplify things a *lot* by decoupling it from clients :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the OP asks about checking for Outlook, i'm guessing this is for windows and not unix. The issue has been covered before in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not) where you can find further details.

I have tried the following snippet which works fine on python 3.4. I only had to install the win32 package via `pip install pypiwin32`.

```
def outlook_is_running():
    import win32ui
    try:
        win32ui.FindWindow(None, "Microsoft Outlook")
        return True
    except win32ui.error:
        return False

if not outlook_is_running():
    import os
    os.startfile("outlook")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what process is started by outlook, and then use this code to check if that process is running:

```
def isprocessrunning(process):
  import re
  import subprocess

  running = False
  processlist = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "ax"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  for a in processlist.stdout:
      if re.search(process, a):
          running = True

  return running

#For Example, 
isprocessrunning("chrome".encode('utf-8'))
#Returns True if Chrome is running
```

Reference:
[Check if a process is running in Python (in Linux/Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647167/check-if-a-process-is-running-in-python-in-linux-unix)